# Evaluation rules in Plot for function

Tags: plotting, manipulate, evaluation

Say I have some test function, which evaluates an integral, such as

```
test[a_, b_] := 
 Integrate[Exp[-(a^2/2) x^2]*Sqrt[x^2 + b^2], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]
```

and in this case returns a confluent hypergeometric function

$$\mathrm{test}(a, b) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{a^2} U \left( -\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{a^2 b^2}{2} \right) \, .$$

I would like to plot the result as a function of $b$ for some value of $a$, e.g. I set $a=1$ and try to plot with

```
Plot[test[1, b], {b, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"b", "test"}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 480]
```

but this takes a very long time to evaluate since Mathematica is repeatedly solving the integral.

This can easily be solved by wrapping an Evaluate around my test function. But now, if I want to manipulate the parameter $a$, things evaluate much slower than if I had just substituted the result, i.e.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[test[a, b]], {b, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"b", "test"}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 480], {{a, 0.5, "a"}, 0.0001, 1, 
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}}]
```

is slower than

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[(Sqrt[\[Pi]] HypergeometricU[-(1/2), 0, (a^2 b^2)/2])/
  a^2, {b, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"b", "test"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> 480], {{a, 0.5, "a"}, 0.0001, 1, 
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}}]
```

Is there a fast way to plot and manipulate the test function without having to substitute the resulting expression by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work better for you?

[image]

```
ClearAll[a, b, x]
test[a_, b_] = 
 Integrate[Exp[-(a^2/2) x^2]*Sqrt[x^2 + b^2], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]

Manipulate[
 Module[{b},
  Plot[test[a0, b], {b, 0, 1},
   AxesLabel -> {"b", "test"},
   PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 480]
  ],
 {{a0, 0.5, "a"}, 0.0001, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a0}
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! Thank you!

Comment: I just noticed that the important change here is the change from SetDelayed to Set in defining the test function (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320330/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed).